# How to replace the value of a string from one protected sub to another

Tags: vb.net, streamwriter

I'm attempting to change the value of a string inside a protected sub from another protected sub to avoid having to copy and paste code more times than I care to count... I've created a sub called EventLogBuilder that I would like to be written to each time a user clicks a button on the page which gives me several protected subs (one for each button). Inside the EventLogBuilder() I have a logBuilder.WriteLine("**How to put text here that comes from another sub**")

```
'Log Builder
Protected Sub EventLogBuilder()

    'Create a streamwriter for the logs...
    Dim logBuilder As StreamWriter

    'Pass the file path and name for the log files...
    logBuilder = New StreamWriter("C:\GateInterfaceLog.txt")

    'Write a test line of text...
    logBuilder.WriteLine("")

    logBuilder.Close()

End Sub
```

And then in one of my buttons I would like to do something like... (Some code removed for clarity)

```
Protected Sub eastOpen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles eastOpen.Click

    'Actions take place here
```

From here I would like to somehow write something that would write back to my EventLogBuilder() method with the new data such as aButtonClick...

Is this possible? OR am I going down the wrong road?

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you pass the string as a variable? `Protected Sub EventLogBuilder(ByVal MyString as String)`

Comment: Because that option wasn't in my vb.net basket until your comment. Thank you. Worked like a champ!

Comment: Put my comment as the answer. Enjoy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pass the string you want as a parameter of the method like so:

```
Protected Sub EventLogBuilder(ByVal LogString as String)

    'Create a streamwriter for the logs...
    Dim logBuilder As StreamWriter

    'Pass the file path and name for the log files...
    logBuilder = New StreamWriter("C:\GateInterfaceLog.txt")

    'Write a test line of text...
    logBuilder.WriteLine(LogString)

    logBuilder.Close()

End Sub
```